# How to convert card reader data from fr-FR to en-US in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

We have a verification (in php/javascript) with a card reader which works o.k.
But when we tried to implement this at a site that uses azerty keyboard the swipe data gets interpreted wrong and thus this user can not be identified.

e.g: swipe data in en-US: `%ESWIPE ACCESS CARD 00159 27102015?`

and with azerty in fr_FR: `5ESZIPE QCCESS CQRD àà&(ç éè&àéà&(§`

Is there a way to solve this preventing me to translate a whole french keyboard manually?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to translate manually, since the usual car reader is a simple "keyboard automatic input device" since its not possible to have 2 layouts at the same time active, a simple translate function will do the trick:

```
$key=array('5' => '%', 'E' => 'E', 'S' => 'W'...);
```

and then

```
$str='5ESZIPE QCCESS CQRD àà&(ç éè&àéà&(§';
$length=strlen($str);
$newstr='';
for ($i=0;$i<$length;++$i) {
  if (in_array($str[$i],$key[$i])) {
    $newstr.=$key[$i];
  }
}
```

To translate the AZERTY to the English version.